# What can we say about $f(\boldsymbol{x})$ if $\nabla f (\boldsymbol{x})\cdot \boldsymbol{x}=f(\boldsymbol{x})$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

What can we say about $f(\boldsymbol{x})$ if $(\nabla f (\boldsymbol{x}))\cdot \boldsymbol{x}=f(\boldsymbol{x})$? Here $\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$. I guess it's a cone, but how to show it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try rewriting the PDE in polar coordinates.

Comment: Why did you put the differential geometry tag here? You mean the *graph* of $f$ is a cone? Do you know Euler's Theorem on homogeneous functions?

Comment: This is actually a first order partial differential equation.
$$x_1\partial_1 u(x_1,x_2)+x_2\partial_2 u(x_1,x_2)=u(x_1,x_2)$$
Solving with the method of characteristics (exercise!) yields
$$u(x_1,x_2)=x_1~g(x_2/x_1)$$
Where $g$ is some differentiable function. So there is a lot of possibilities.